# Can these Star Wars characters as emojis be identified?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, rogue-one

I came across this picture from a *Star Wars* fan page. They seem to be characters from the upcoming *Rogue One* film, but since they done in an emoji/funko pop style it is hard for me to tell who they are...

[image: id picture]

Can these characters be identified?

Comment: I give you my vote, because these are fun questions.

Comment: @JackBNimble Wait, we are supposed to have *fun* here?

Comment: @Skooba No, we are supposed to *not* have fun here. But some of us are subversive daredevils ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. [Jyn Erso](http://www.starwars.com/databank/jyn-erso)

   [image]
2. [Bodhi Rook](http://www.starwars.com/databank/bodhi-rook)

   [image]
3. [K-2SO](http://www.starwars.com/databank/k-2so-kay-tuesso)

   [image]
4. [Mon Mothma](http://www.starwars.com/databank/mon-mothma)

   [image]
5. [Saw Gerrera](http://www.starwars.com/databank/saw-gerrera)

   [image]
6. [Bistan](http://www.starwars.com/databank/bistan)

   [image]

   Bistan is the hardest because he hasn't appeared in a trailer; he was shown briefly in a [behind-the-scenes sizzle reel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUb_zpdyDpU), where his unusual appearance earned him the fan nickname "space monkey". His real name (and species) were revealed by Pablo Hidalgo [at Celebration Europe 2016](https://youtu.be/JGCR89WQ87g?t=51s)<sup>1</sup>.
7. [Cassian Andor](http://www.starwars.com/databank/captain-cassian-andor)

   [image]
8. [Death Trooper](http://www.starwars.com/databank/imperial-death-troopers)

   [image]
9. [Chirrut Îmwe](http://www.starwars.com/databank/chirrut-imwe)

   [image]
10. [Baze Malbus](http://www.starwars.com/databank/baze-malbus)

    [image]
11. [Orson Krennic](http://www.starwars.com/databank/director-orson-krennic)

    [image]

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to NKCampbell for the video link

Comment: StarWars.com canon source for Bistan: (Word of almost God Pablo Hidalgo video embedded on the news story page) - http://makingstarwars.net/2016/07/new-details-on-bistan-from-rogue-one-a-star-wars-story/

Comment: @NKCampbell Cheers; added that in